# Webapp Webjob logs not appearning in storage container

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-continuous

I have a webapp for which I have configured the App setting under configuration "AzureWebJobsDashboard" and "Azurewebjobstorage" which has the value for storage account and its access key.

As described in this article : https://www.marathonus.com/about/blog/introduction-to-azure-webjobs/
Once I set these setting and restart the app service, logs should appear in two storage containers as below

```
azure-webjobs-hosts
azure-jobs-host-output
```

However I see only  azure-webjobs-hosts created and logging happening only sometimes. While I check for the webjob logs via Kudu site, I can see logs under the jobs folder, my job in txt files.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the steps from the blog which you have provided and created one web job.
And Created one storage account and configured with the web job and published it into azure.
I can see created log files in storage account and kudu site.
You can restart your webjobs and check the storage account for the newly created logs.

[image]